# Totalling order values in a spreadsheet depending on coming from a EU or NON EU country

Tags: spreadsheet

In a Spreadsheet I have a list of invoices showing Invoice Total and Customers Country etc. I need to get a total for all EU orders and total NON EU orders.

At the moment I create a new column and manually go down each row looking at the Country and in the new column enter EU or ROW as appropriate and then sort on that column and do a total on the Invoice Total column for the EU and NON EU which are now in two bocks.

This is very time consuming. Is there any macro or automated way of doing it.

Something else that would be a benefit and that is if a macro could be set to show the number of orders from each country so Australia 7, Austria 18 etc.

Most of the Spreadsheets used above have the Invoice Totals al in GBP so totalling is not a problem but one of our websites is .com and we receive orders in £, € and US$. The invoice total shown on that Spreadsheet shows the currency symbol at the start of invoice amount.

In this case we have to manually convert for each invoice in € or US$ this amount to GB Pounds before we total can this be automate if we say in a particular cell input the exchange rate for the € and in another cell the exchange rate for the US$.

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `lookup()`.

You need a lookup table to make it work, this table consists of two columns (all possible countries, and next column if its EU or ROW). You can make this manually, or copy it somewhere.

Now you set the cell value to =lookup() with searching the value in your table (e.g. "france") in your lookup-table you made before. The result will automatically show EU or ROW.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3256570?hl=en

To translate the currency you could use the "if()" function.
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093364?hl=en

if(A1 = "$", A2*D1, A2)

Means: if you have the "$" in the cell A1, multiply the value in A2 with the exchange rate (which in this example is set in D1), else don't change the value.